# C++ Look through Columns of data

Tags: c++, getline

I have a datafile that is MASSIVE, and I can't load it all into memory to look through it. How can I sort through the file looking for specific values (it is latitude, longitude, altitude, and I am looking for the two altitude values that bound a specific altitude, which I will interpolate around to find specific lat/lon points)? I can read each line with a "getline()", but that won't let me look at two values and compare them to my specific value I want (as far as I know).

Thanks.

Comment: Would it work to store two values at a time and check them? How would I do that effectively?

Comment: I guess the value that is to be bounded is known ahead of time, the other two are not?

Comment: Are you just asking how to parse the numeric values out of a string, so you can compare them?

Comment: I can parse them just fine, the problem I'm facing is comparing two values in the altitude column to a specified value (say 10,000) so that I can interpolate between the two values to get the lat/lon at 10,000. The data file is over 1GB in size, so I can't load it into memory then search through it.

Comment: What is the format of the file?  If it's just three numbers per line, this is a fairly easy exercise.

Comment: the question is unclear, I was thinking you need to sort a huge file.

Answer (score 0):

- Since your file is relatively small, you can split the file into 4 250MB files and search inside those.
- Read small chunks from the files and search inside those chunks for the values. This is linear time.
- Sort the file. You can easily do it by reading small chunks and sorting each chunk with Quicksort (it does it in place). After a chunk is sorted dump it to disk. After all chunks are sorted and on disk, start reading a few values from each chunk and hold those in memory (call these new_chunks) Then start merging the values together into a larger file. Whenever the values from a new_chunk are used and moved into the larger file, cache more from their respective original, now srted, chunk. After this process is over, you should have a sorted file.
  This improves a bit searching, but you still have to do linear search bringing parts of the large sorted file into memory so it is also linear time.
- A better way is after you sorted the file as in the step above, then have indexes in memory. Map index to location in file/on disk. This way you can improve seek time within the file.

  > For example, if your files has numbers likes 1,2,3,...100. Index the file, by storing in memory (number in file:position in file/position on disk) 1:0,10:9,20:19...
  >   Now if you're looking for number 18 you do a binary search in these indexes (logn time) and you find that 18 is between 10 and 20, so you read the file at position 9 to 19 and bring that chunk into memory.
  >   Now perform another binary search in that chunk: logm time

  Total runtime: logn+logm or log(num_index_chunks)+log(avg_size_of_chunk)+chunk_i_load_time

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to find the two consecutive lines/rows between which the altitude crosses the target value? In that case, you could just store the previous altitude between iterations of `getline()`. Then, on any line, if the current altitude is greater than the target, and the previous is less than the target, or vice versa, you've crossed the target altitude, and output whatever you need to output (possibly save the entire previous line so you can interpolate lat/long).